# Get a value from Firebase and update it with the current value + 1

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, react-native

So yeah the title has the question. A little information this is what my Firebase database looks like:

[image: firebase database]

And this is the current code:

```
export function updateQTY(barcode) {
  database.ref('items/' + barcode).update({
    qty: currentQTY(barcode)
  })
}
export function currentQTY(barcode) {
  database.ref('items/' + barcode).once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
    var qty = snapshot.val().qty
    console.log(qty)
  })
  return qty + 1
}
```

Basically, What I want is for the qty + 1 to be returned to the function `updateQTY`.

Maby I have to do a completely different way but that's fine, I just don't understand how to do it. I understand the fact that the function that actually gets the current qty has to return it, but then I don't understand how to catch it in the other function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't return a value which won't be available right away, so `currentQTY` needs to return a *promise* for the new quantity; then, in `updateQTY`, wait for that promise to fulfill and **then** update the data.

```
export function updateQTY(barcode) {
  return currentQTY(barcode)
    .then(qty => database.ref('items/' + barcode).update({qty}));
)

export function currentQTY(barcode): Promise<number> {
  return database.ref('items/' + barcode).once('value')
    .then(snapshot => snapshot.val().qty + 1);
}
```

If you can use async/await:

```
export async function updateQTY(barcode) {
  const qty = await currentQTY(barcode);

  database.ref('items/' + barcode).update({qty}));
)
```

Or even

```
export async function updateQTY(barcode) {
  database.ref('items/' + barcode).update({qty: await currentQTY(barcode)});
)
```

However, you could accomplish this more easily and robustly with transactions:

```
export function updateQTY(barcode) {
  return database.ref('items/' + barcode).transaction(data => {
    data.qty++;
    return data;
  });
}
```

Or if you prefer

```
export function updateQTY(barcode) {
  return database.ref(`items/{$barcode}/qty`).transaction(qty => qty++);
}
```

Using transactions has the advantage that it will correctly handle situations in which multiple users are trying to update the data at the same time. For more information, see the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#save_data_as_transactions).