# Flutter firebase transaction

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I want to update data in fire base by plus it by a value. Ex: `data = data + 1` I've read this article [Get a value from Firebase and update it with the current value + 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43442796/get-a-value-from-firebase-and-update-it-with-the-current-value-1) and the top answer uses `transaction` to deal with it. But I cannot find `transaction` function in `cloud_firestore: ^0.16.0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That answer is for Firebase's Realtime Database, while you are using Cloud Firestore.

To atomically increment a value in Firestore, you can use its [transaction API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions), or you can use its [`increment` operation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#increment_a_numeric_value), which makes it much easier.

It could be as simple as:

```
documentRef.update({
    data: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1)
});
```